# Using the implicit JSF converter javax.faces.convert.EnumConverter explicitly in p:dataTable filters

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, enums, converters

Enum :

```
public enum OrderStatus {

    New("New"),
    Paid("Paid"),
    Shipped("Shipped"),
    Completed("Completed");

    private final String label;

    private OrderStatus(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

Using `enum` type in a `<p:dataTable>` filter as follows.

```
<p:dataTable var="row"
             value="#{testBacking}"
             lazy="true"
             rows="10"
             widgetVar="dataTableUIWidget">

    <p:column id="id" headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{row.orderId}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Order Status" filterBy="#{row.orderStatus}">
        <f:facet name="filter">
            <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('dataTableUIWidget').filter();">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue=""/>

                <f:selectItems var="orderStatus"
                               value="#{enumBean.orderStatus}" 
                               itemLabel="#{orderStatus.label}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{row.orderStatus}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

`row.orderStatus` is a type of the above `enum` in its associated JPA entity.

The filter associated with the `<p:selectOneMenu>` needs to specify the `javax.faces.convert.EnumConverter` explicitly, since its value is not bound to a backing bean property (else an appropriate converter would have appropriately played its role implicitly on its own based on the type of the property in the associated backing bean).

I expect that mentioning a converter as follows

```
<f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Enum"/>
```

should work as other implicit converters.

This however, causes an issue (when `<f:converter>` is specified as said above).

> Severe:   JSF1006: Cannot instantiate converter of type javax.faces.Enum

What is the issue with this converter? I am seeking for a workable solution.

Using PrimeFaces 5.2 final / Mojarra 2.2.12.

---

**Additional :**

The [converter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.11/javax/faces/convert/EnumConverter.java#EnumConverter) specifies `javax.faces.Enum` as `converterId`.

```
public class EnumConverter implements Converter, PartialStateHolder {

    public static final String CONVERTER_ID = "javax.faces.Enum";
    public static final String ENUM_ID = "javax.faces.converter.EnumConverter.ENUM";
    public static final String ENUM_NO_CLASS_ID = "javax.faces.converter.EnumConverter.ENUM_NO_CLASS";
    private Class<? extends Enum> targetClass;
    private boolean isTransient;
    private boolean initialState;

    public EnumConverter() {}
}
```

Therefore, this should work by specifying `javax.faces.Enum` as `convertId` of `<f:converter>` as other implicit JSF converters.

The bean used in the above test-case (completely optional to be peer reviewed) :

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBacking extends LazyDataModel<OrderTable> implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private OrderService orderService;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestBacking() {}

    @Override
    public List<OrderTable> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {

        if (MapUtils.isNotEmpty(filters)) { // Debugging purpose only.
            System.out.println("Enum filter : " + (filters.get("orderStatus") instanceof OrderStatus));
            System.out.println("Filter value : " + filters.get("orderStatus"));
        }

        int rowCount = MapUtils.isNotEmpty(filters) ? orderService.rowCount(filters).intValue() : orderService.rowCount().intValue();
        setRowCount(rowCount);

        return orderService.getList(first, pageSize, null, filters);
    }
}
```

The `stdout` statements inside the `load()` method display the following output.

```
Enum filter : false
Filter value : New
```

(`filters.get("orderStatus") instanceof OrderStatus` returns `false` as obvious, since the filter component `<p:selectOneMenu>` is not passed through the converter. It simply returns `String` without conversion).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `EnumConverter` is a special converter which can only be constructed with a `Class<E>` as argument (which ultimately get set as `targetClass`). Without it, the converter won't work. It unfortunately isn't usable across all enums (i.e. it's actually not a "generic enum converter"). 
There where you assumed implicit/automatic conversion on enums, it's actually done by EL coercion, not by JSF `EnumConverter`. EL has indeed generic support for enums as long as the target type is resolveable as an enum.

To explicitly use the JSF enum converter, you basically need to extend `EnumConverter` like below to pass the target enum into c'tor (no need to override the `getAsString/Object()` methods):

```
@FacesConverter(value="orderStatusConverter")
public class OrderStatusConverter extends EnumConverter {

    public OrderStatusConverter() {
        super(OrderStatus.class);
    }

}
```

And then reference it instead:

```
<f:converter converterId="orderStatusConverter" />
```

Don't forget to alter `<f:selectItem itemValue="">` to be `itemValue="#{null}"`, or you will get a `ClassCastException` on `java.lang.String`.

If you happen to use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), you can also use its [generic enum converter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/GenericEnumConverter) instead:

```
<f:converter converterId="omnifaces.GenericEnumConverter" />
```